# is it ethical for a supervisor to exert pressure on a student because he is doing a project with a company?

Tags: graduate-school, ethics, funding

I am currently a first year master student. My supervisor is having a project with a car company and this work was mainly assigned to a Phd student in my lab who volunteered for it. During the work, my professor got a side ideal from that project and assigned it for me as my master thesis topic. But for some reason, my supervisor keep exerting pressure and pushing me to run his deadline with the company and his demand is sometime ridiculously impossible to achieve. And after couple months, I realized that if I continued doing this topic, I might have to postpone my graduation. I am paying my study expense from a student loan with 0% of interest, and the provider only give me the loan within 2 years. And I am feeling that my supervisor is dictating me to do free work for him instead of guiding me to get my master degree.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: If you finish the project and have a write-up on it, did your supervisor say it will be your master thesis?

Comment: It sounds like you have a bunch of complaints rather than a specific question.

Comment: Thank you for replying me @scaaahu: no the work is just started.  @ Anonymous Physicist: yes , it is both complain and also my dilemma situation

Comment: So much missing information to answer: Is it usual to have an industry-oriented thesis at your university? Do you/him get paid? Will you even be able to include the work in your MSc or are you bound by NDA? Do you have a tutor (academic advisor)? Can you switch thesis or have you done too much work? Will the work lead to a publication? If yes, is this something you want? Is there a chance you continue working for the company? If yes, is this something you want?